# Displaying shared mailbox calendar from outlook on modern Sharepoint site/page

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way to sync/display a Shared mailbox calendar in outlook onto a Sharepoint page?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, there is currently no OOTB web part to display Shared mailbox calendar from Exchange/Outlook on the SharePoint Online page.

**Here is a similar post for your reference:**

- [Displaying an Exchange Shared Mailbox Calendar on SharePoint
  Online](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/displaying-an-exchange-shared-mailbox-calendar-on-sharepoint/m-p/1611661)